# Why the overlay arrow in tikz not coming in correct place?

Tags: tikz-pgf, beamer, equations, tikz-arrows

I am trying to put overlay arrows to describe parts of a mathematical expression using `tikz` as below. However, I am unable to position the arrows properly.

All I am getting is this:
[image]

How can I place them correctly to point the three parts of the expression to the labels `AAAA`, `BBBBBBB` and `CCCCCCCCCC`?

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,shapes}

\begin{document}
    \begin{frame}
        \frametitle{Hello World}
        \begin{block}{Formulation}
        \tikzstyle{na} = [baseline=-.5ex]
                \vspace{0.6em}
                \begin{itemize}
                    \item Equation is 

                    \begin{equation}
                    \tikz[baseline]{\node[rounded corners,
                        fill=blue!10,draw=blue!30,anchor=base] (t12) {$AAAAA$};}
                    +p\,\,
                    \tikz[baseline]{\node[rounded corners,
                        fill=green!10,draw=green!30, anchor=base] (t22) {$BBBBB$};
                    }+q\,\,
                    \tikz[baseline]{\node[rounded corners,
                        fill=orange!10,draw=orange!30,anchor=base] (t32) {$CCCCCCC$};
                    }\nonumber
                    \end{equation}
                    AAAA\tikz[na] \node[coordinate] (n12) {}; \hfill
                      BBBBBBB\tikz[na] \node[coordinate] (n22) {};\hfill
                      \tikz[na] \node[coordinate] (n32) {};CCCCCCCCCC \\

                    \begin{tikzpicture}[overlay]
                    \path[->]<1-> (n12) edge[bend right](t12);
                    \path[->]<1-> (n22.north) edge[bend right](t22);
                    \path[->]<1-> (n32.west) edge[bend left](t32);
                    \end{tikzpicture}

               \end{itemize}                    
            \end{block}
    \end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You need `\tikz[remember picture,...` throughout, and `\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]` where the arrows are drawn.,

Comment: @TorbjørnT.  Is the first `\tikz[remember...` to be applied everywhere, e.g. in the `\tikz[na]`, etc also ? I will try soon. Thanks.

Comment: Yes, you have multiple `\tikz` commands, and all of those need to have `remember picture` as an option.

Comment: Thanks! It simply worked. But I remember, earlier, more than a year ago, I used it without any `remember` and it worked then.

Comment: I seriously doubt that, to be honest, but it could have been hidden away in a style.

Comment: @TorbjørnT. Would you like to convert your comment into an answer?

Comment: @samcarter Well, sure. I was looking for a duplicate earlier (would be surprised if one didn't exist), but I couldn't find a good one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order for TikZ to be able to properly reuse coordinates from other `tikzpicture`s, you need to have `remember picture` in the options for the environment/`\tikz` macro.

Hence, if you just add `remember picture` as an option to all your `\tikz` macros, and the `tikzpicture` enviroment, your code works fine. Or alternatively, say `\tikzset{every picture/.append style={remember picture}}` inside the `frame`.

[image]

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,shapes}

\begin{document}
    \begin{frame}
        \frametitle{Hello World}
        \begin{block}{Formulation}
                \vspace{0.6em}
                \tikzset{
                    na/.style={baseline=-.5ex},
                    % every picture/.append style={remember picture} % alternative to having remember picture everywhere below
                }
                \begin{itemize}
                    \item Equation is 

                    \begin{equation}
                    \tikz[baseline,remember picture]{\node[rounded corners,
                        fill=blue!10,draw=blue!30,anchor=base] (t12) {$AAAAA$};}
                    +p\,\,
                    \tikz[baseline,remember picture]{\node[rounded corners,
                        fill=green!10,draw=green!30, anchor=base] (t22) {$BBBBB$};
                    }+q\,\,
                    \tikz[baseline,remember picture]{\node[rounded corners,
                        fill=orange!10,draw=orange!30,anchor=base] (t32) {$CCCCCCC$};
                    }\nonumber
                    \end{equation}
                    AAAA\tikz[na,remember picture] \node[coordinate] (n12) {}; \hfill
                      BBBBBBB\tikz[na,remember picture] \node[coordinate] (n22) {};\hfill
                      \tikz[na,remember picture] \node[coordinate] (n32) {};CCCCCCCCCC \\

                    \begin{tikzpicture}[overlay,remember picture]
                    \path[->]<1-> (n12) edge[bend right](t12);
                    \path[->]<1-> (n22.north) edge[bend right](t22);
                    \path[->]<1-> (n32.west) edge[bend left](t32);
                    \end{tikzpicture}

               \end{itemize}                    
            \end{block}
    \end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Hi! Could you kindly tell me then, an use case of when `remember picture` is not used? It seems to me that this flag is  always required in practice. Thanks.

Comment: @ffslq On the contrary, `remember picture` is the exception. It's used whenever you need to reference a coordinate in a *different* `tikzpicture`. So it's not used when you don't need that, which is most diagrams.